# Visual Studio browser link just hosed my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I just tried using Browser link in Visual Studio.  Big mistake.  By doing so, it seems to have overwritten my view (.cshtml) with the rendered page (with the actuak values instead of the calls to @Model.xxxx.  Is there a way to revert the page after it has done this?

Comment: As I understand, you have problems running your project, just right clic to your solution and clic revert or undo, if there are problems of your IDE, just try to restart your visual studio, if any of these works, comment or be more specific about your problem please.

Comment: No, there is no "revert" or "undo" option at the solution level (at lease I don't see one in the context menu).

Comment: What I had done was launched the application (site) and then went to the Browser link  options and entered "design mode" and made changes from within the browser which directly changed the view file which at that point had been opened by VS.

Comment: Unfortunately though, the view file had now had all of its dynamic elements replaced with the actual contents that were rendered to the browser. (i.e. "@Model.xxx" was replaced by the actual value of the object, "@Html.TextBox" had been replaced by "<input type="text".....>, etc.).  I just tried to reproduce this behavior and this time around, when in design mode using browser link, dynamic elements of the page were not changed.  So, I'm not sure what happened the first time.